# Validating Phone Numbers in Batch with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT
    countries.locl_ctry_id,
    countries.icc,
    countries.active,

    networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
    networks.locl_ctry_id,

    numberings.locl_ntwrk_id,
    numberings.ndc,
    numberings.size

FROM countries

LEFT JOIN networks
    ON networks.locl_ctry_id = countries.locl_ctry_id

LEFT JOIN numberings
    ON numberings.locl_ntwrk_id = networks.locl_ntwrk_id

WHERE
    countries.active = 'true'
AND numberings.locl_ntwrk_id NOTNULL
AND CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc) 
  LIKE LEFT('381645554330', CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc)))
AND LENGTH('381645554330') = numberings.size
```

I would like to run this script for a batch of numbers, for example:

- 381645554330 ‭
- 381629000814‬‬
- 381644446555‬
- ‭38975300155‬
- ‭38975604099 ‭
- 38976330923‬‬ ‭
- 38977772090‬ ‭
- 38978250177‬ ‭
- 38970333730‬
- ‭38971388262‬
- ‭38972228855‬

**Take a look at the database structure here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/13ce29/27**

It needs to validate the `Prefix` as well as the `Length` of the number.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The previous question doesn't take length into account. Was asked to post another one.

Comment: And do you want it to only show numbers that fail or pass?

Comment: Pass. But it's fine if it also shows all. @CaiusJard

Comment: Have you loaded the numbers you wish to validate, into the database also?

Comment: @CaiusJard It needs to get the numbers from the lookup query, they are dynamic so wont be in the database.

Comment: I'm starting to not see what the question is; if the query works with 381645554330 why not replace 381645554330  with 381629000814‬‬ and run it again?

Comment: Because I want to limit the request to the database. Want everything sent of as a batch in 1 request.

Answer (score 0):

Put the batch of numbers in a union all subquery.

```
SELECT
    countries.locl_ctry_id,
    countries.icc,
    countries.active,

    networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
    networks.locl_ctry_id,

    numberings.locl_ntwrk_id,
    numberings.ndc,
    numberings.size

FROM countries

LEFT JOIN networks
    ON networks.locl_ctry_id = countries.locl_ctry_id

LEFT JOIN numberings
    ON numberings.locl_ntwrk_id = networks.locl_ntwrk_id

JOIN ( select '381645554330' as num
       union all
       select '38976330923‬‬‬‬'
       union all
       select '38975300155‬‬‬' ) batch_numbers 
  ON CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc) 
  LIKE LEFT(batch_numbers.num, CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc)))
  AND LENGTH(batch_numbers.num) = numberings.size

WHERE
    countries.active = 'true'
AND numberings.locl_ntwrk_id NOTNULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the objective is not ability to return the set of values currently returned by the single, but to make an evaluation of the of multiple values. The issue with the above it requires an a-priori knowledge of and a modification to the query for each set to evaluate. The follow will attempt to remove that requirement. 
Let's begin by developing a base line query as an extension to Jakup's "union" solution.

```
--- create a baseline solution  
with to_be_validated (test_num) as  -- CTE used strictly as data generator fir query
  ( values ('381645554330')
         , ('381629000814')
         , ('381644446555')
         , ('38975300155')
         , ('38975604099')
         , ('38976330923')
         , ('38977772090')
         , ('38978250177')
         , ('38970333730')
         , ('38971388262')
         , ('38972228855')
         , ('81771388262')
         , ('55572228855')         
  )  
  --- base query         
   select test_num
        , case when icc is not null then 'Valid' else 'Invalid' end validation
  from to_be_validated 
  left join(
            select countries.icc, numberings.ndc,  numberings.size
             from countries
             join networks on networks.locl_ctry_id = countries.locl_ctry_id
             join numberings on numberings.locl_ntwrk_id = networks.locl_ntwrk_id
           ) base on (    concat(base.icc, base.ndc) = left( test_num, char_length(concat(base.icc, base.ndc))) 
                      and length(test_num) = base.size
                     )
;
```

Notes on Query and Modifications:
 1. the column countries.active is defined as binary, thus already providing a True/False value. Thus checking for "= 'true' is unnecessary. Altered  to just contries.active.
 2. The column numberings.locl_ntwrk_id is restricted to being NOT NULL, so the Predicate "nullnumberings.locl_ntwrk_id NOTNULL" is always true. Removed predicate.
 3. The LEFT JOIN on networks and numberings will generate a result set with all countries, all networks, all numberings, even when the combination is itself invalid. This results in validating each phone number against every combination of the 3 base tables. Alter these inner joins.
 4. Finally, I added a couple extra numbers to your test data. These are intended to fail the desired validation. You should always test with considerable invalid data, otherwise you cannot know if procedure/query/whatever gracefully and properly handles it.

Now with a base query in hand it's possible to just end here. But to be generally useful you cannot edit the query each time it wanted. Therefore lets wrap a function definition around it. We'll do this by wrapping a function definition around that base query, and provide either an array or a delimited string containing the phone numbers to b evaluated. 
In each the base query remains the same, and we keep the CTE, but the CTE is modified to build a row for each phone number provided.

```
-- SQL Function with and Array input 
create or replace function validate_phone_numbers( phone_numbers text[])
returns table ( phone_number text
              , validation_status text
              )
language sql
as $$
with to_be_validated as
        (  select unnest (phone_numbers) test_num  )
-- Insert base query here --
$$ 

-- Test with Array 
  select phone_number, validation_status
    from validate_phone_numbers (ARRAY 
                                [ ('381629000814')    
                                , ('381644446555')            
                                , ('38975300155')             
                                , ('38975604099')             
                                , ('38976330923')             
                                , ('38977772090')             
                                , ('38978250177')             
                                , ('38970333730')             
                                , ('38971388262')             
                                , ('38972228855')            
                                , ('81771388262')     
                                , ('55572228855')
                                ]
                      ) ;
```

With a minor extension we a delimited string version.

```
create or replace function validate_phone_numbers_with_string( phone_numbers text, delimiter text default ',')
returns table ( phone_number text
              , validation_status text
              )
language sql
as $$
with to_be_validated as
        (  select unnest (string_to_array (phone_numbers, delimiter)) test_num)
-- Insert base query here --
$$ ;

-- test  with string
select phone_number, validation_status
  from validate_phone_numbers_with_string('381629000814,381644446555,38975300155,38975604099,38976330923,38977772090,38978250177,38970333730,38971388262,38972228855,81771388262,55572228855');
```